# Imagem na tela do CAPTCHA não está aparecendo

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

A imagem na tela do CAPTCHA não está aparecendo, o link da imagem é

- http://cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/captcha.jpg

[image: erro imagem]

Comment: É sabotagem para você não responder à pergunta :)

Comment: E o link da página qual é?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto foi resolvido, obrigado! Você pode conferir a solução [pelo link direto para a tela de CAPTCHA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/captcha).

---

This has been fixed, thank you! You can see the fix by [forcing yourself to get a CAPTCHA here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/captcha).

Comment: Ha, nice picture, brings me good memories. I guess it was picked by Gabe, right? | He, legal a imagem, me traz boas lembranças. Só pode ter sido escolhida pelo Gabe, né?

Comment: Correto, looks like Gabe made a good choice :)

Comment: @gabe mandou bem nessa hein.